# Webpack refusing to match loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I've been back and forth with this for 2 days now before just admitting defeat. What I'm trying to do is load in a jquery plugin thats not setup for any module system and I've tried possibly several dozen approaches before realizing that the culprit all-along was that it was never matching my loader in the first place.

Here is my current loader

```
{
    test: /\/src\/scripts\/lib\/.*\.js$/,
    loaders: ["imports?this=>window,define=>false"]
}
```

I'm trying to match all javascript files in /src/scripts/lib folder (they may be in subfolders)

Now I've also tried this without the file ending without any luck

```
test: /\/src\/scripts\/lib\//,
```

Growing more frustrated I also tried this and placed a dummy script in the lib folder

```
loaders: ["imports?this=>window,define=>false,isHere=>true"]
```

but isHere was undefined telling me that the past 2 days all my attempts were never tried in the first place because the loader was never being matched.

My goal is to make a module wrapper around non-module script files to help prevent globals and such but I'm not looking for anything complicated and will settle with globals if it means moving on from this.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: your import url looks strange, try using `=` instead of `=>` and `&` instead of `,`

Comment: I was going by the instructions on the site which say to use it like that and separate them by commas https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader. It says a regular equal sign does a package require and a `=>` creates a local variable in the package of a certain value which can be used to redefine this, disable amd code by unsetting define, and other variables